# Could "if at all possible" be used as a concessive clause?

Tags: grammar

Can I use "if at all possible" like as follows?

> If at all possible, you shouldn't do that.

meaning "Even if you can do that, you shouldn't".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

While the sentence is grammatical, (though a native speaker would place the "if at all possible" at the end) it doesn't mean what you think it does. "You shouldn't do that, if at all possible" would mean "you shouldn't do that if there's any way you can avoid it." In this case, "if at all possible" is amplifying the clause "you shouldn't do that."

Concessive clauses, by definition, express an idea that is the opposite of the main part of the sentence.

> "Although he's young, he's very experienced."

Here the listener is being assured that "he" is more experienced than we would normally expect someone to be at "his" age.

> "Even though she ate lunch, she was hungry."

"She" is hungry despite eating "her" lunch.

> "He bought her an expensive gift, even though he couldn't afford it."

Here we are told "he" can't do something, while also being told "he" went ahead and did it anyway.

Another way to think of concessive clauses is that they generally have to concede or admit something. In my first example, we admit that "he" is young, but we add that "he" has experience.

> "Even though it's a terrible film, I enjoy The Room"

"I" admits that The Room is a bad movie that "I" likes anyway.

> "Although I lied, it was for your own good."

"I" admits that "I" lied, but "I" tries to justify it by claiming the lies benefited "you" as much or more than the truth would have.

The phrase "if at all possible" just doesn't have a meaning that lends itself to concessive clauses.

Comment: Thank you. So "if at all" can be used as a concessive such as "I never lied, if at all, it was for your sake" (meaning "even if I did"), while "if at all possible" can't be used as one? English is so hard to learn :D

Comment: @dolco not exactly. "If at all" isn't concessive, either. If I wanted to justify any lies I may or may not have told, I'd say "I never lied, but if I did, it was for your sake." But that's not concessive, either, because I didn't express an opposing idea. "Never lied" agrees with "your sake." "Although I lied, it was for your sake," does contain the concessive clause "although," and "I lied" is at odds with "your sake."